# How to connect Tor to the web using a specific server?

Tags: tor, geolocation

Some websites restrict access based on which country the accessing IP comes from. I'd like to use TOR to circumvent such restrictions. So I'd like to use an exit node that's located in a specific country.

How do I configure TOR to use an exit node that's located in a specific country? Or alternatively, how do I use a specific exit node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible. You have to edit your Tor config. Vidalia Control Canel > Settings > Advanced > Edit current torrc.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit

You have to add:

```
ExitNodes {ua}
StrictNodes 1
```

"ua" is Ukrainian 2 letter country code. Be advised that bandwidth and latency over Tor are very poor.

Comment: For what it's worth, changing [`StrictNodes`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes) shouldn't necessary for this purpose. It doesn't matter what country's relays you use to connect to an onion, for example.